# Is it possible to install TFS Build Service on Domain server while connecting to TFS server installed on non-Domain server

Tags: tfsbuild

My scenario is:

I installed TFS server 2012 (application tie) on server (s1) in a **workgroup**. Then I installed TFS 2012 Build service on server (s2) in a **domain** (d1).

I created a user (build_user) on both s1 and the Domain Controller of s2 with same password.

Then I started the TFS Administration Console -> Build Configuration -> Configure Installed Features -> configure build service -> Connected to TFS server on s1 -> Run build service as: "build_user", when I clicked "Test", it passed -> everything went well. But after I clicked "Configure", I got an error saying **user "d1\build_user" not found**.

Must I install the TFS build service on server that is in workgroup? If not, how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, except my TFS Server is on my domain and my build servers are not.  You should be able to set it up as follows:

1. Ensure that both machines have a **build_user** with the same password.
2. Log into the Build machine as **build_user**
3. Load `Control Panel` -> `Credential Manager`
4. Create the following credentials:

   - **Windows Credential**

     - Network Address: IP Address of TFS Server
     - User name: workgropup\build_user
   - **Generic Credential**

     - Network Address: `http://AddressOfTFSServer:8080/`
     - User name: workgroup\build_user
   - **Generic Credential**

     - Network Address: `http://AddressOfTFSServer:8080/tfs`
     - User name: workgroup\build_user
   - **Generic Credential**

     - Network Address: `http://AddressOfTFSServer:8080/tfs/collectionname`
     - User name: workgroup\build_user

The above may need tinkering with to suit your setup,  but the above allows me to connect a non-domain build server to a domain TFS Server.

I hope this helps.