# Run a TFS2012 Build Service on a Machine in an untrusted domain

Tags: tfsbuild

TFS 2012 Server Update 2

I'm trying to follow the following the blog below to achive creating a build service on another domain.

[Specify the account used to connect to your Team Foundation Server (section)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712%28vs.110%29.aspx#interactive)

The build machine is on a different domain b(untrusted) than the domain a TFS server.

> I have 2 accounts
>
> domaina\tfsbuild
>
> and  domainb\tfsbuild
>
> they both have the same passwords.

When I try to register a build service using TFS Admin Console:

> Run the Service as: domainb\tfsbuild
>
> Connect to Team Foundation Server as: domaina\tfsbuild

I'm getting an error "TFS254021: The account name or password you specified is not valid.  Is it a requirement to have both domaina and domainb on a trust relationship?

its similar/related to this question i [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118258/is-it-possible-to-install-tfs-build-service-on-domain-server-while-connecting-to):

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes. [TFS authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253184.aspx#Authent) is based on Windows Authentication. It is possible to provide access to TFS from domains other than the one TFS is in but you must establish a trust relationship between those domains. Otherwise you will not be able to access your TFS server from another domain. Check out [Trusts and Forests Considerations for Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253081.aspx).